# How 9patchimage works?

Tags: android

I am working with android's 9 patch image emulator to create 9 patch image.

Can anyone tell me how it actually works?
On what basis it Scale the image?
What are the parameters it considers to stretch image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are great paragraphs about 9 patch drawables https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a **PNG image with 1px border** around it. With the black pixels on the border you define an area witch is stretchable and area in which the content is allowed.

More information under [the link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) provided by Konstatin.